# GTM - Truncated DataLayer Variable into Custom Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I currently have a dlv variable to store "First Name" (gtm.element.2.value) which is working correctly.

I also a dlv to store "D.O.B." which is also working correctly - gtm.element.5.value (this is formatted MM/DD/YYYY).

However, I'd like to only show the first initial in the First Name dlv and the Year in the DOB dlv.  I'm thinking of utilizing a Custom JS variable but am open to ideas if there is an easier route.

Can anyone help provide what that Custom JS variable would look like?  I've been searching for some examples but not having luck with this specific example.

Appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To get the first initial (i.e. first character) of the First Name variable, you can indeed use a Custom JavaScript variable with this:

```
function() {
  return {{first_name}}[0]; // Replace with the actual DLV reference
}
```

Similarly, to get just the year (YYYY) of the D.O.B., you can use a Custom JS variable:

```
function() {
  return {{date_of_birth}}.split('/').pop(); // Replace with the actual DLV reference
}
```

Obviously you might want to add some checks to make sure the input is in a predictable format. For example, you might want to check that `{{first_name}}` is a string of non-zero length, and you might want to check that `{{date_of_birth}}` actually contains a date string with slash as the separator.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Here's the script I've added - function() {
  return {{gtm.element.2.value}}[0]; // Replace with the actual DLV reference
} - but I'm getting this error "Unknown variable “gtm.element.2.value” found in another variable. Edit the variable and remove the reference to the unknown variable."